# Programmatically set position of Swift element

Tags: ios, swift

I have a label defined in Storyboard and I'm trying to change its position based programatically.  There are some existing questions on SO already that seem to address this issue, but none of the solutions seem to work (i.e., the label doesn't move).  I've removed all existing constraints on the label to no avail.  I've tried:

```
class LandingViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(100, 25, titleLabel.frame.size.width, titleLabel.frame.size.height)
        }
```

I also tried

`titleLabel.center = CGPointMake(120, 150)`

instead of `titleLabel.frame`

Am I missing something?

Comment: _Where_ (in which function) are you setting `frame`?

Comment: titleLabel is declared at the top, and then the above code is in viewDidLoad().  I'll edit to add context.

Comment: Are you using auto layout ? If so, you have to change its contraints to place it without changing its frame. Just call `titleLabel.layoutIfNeeded()` after

Comment: Do you have this `titleLabel` outlet connected in your storyboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using AutoLayout, views instantiated in storyboards with constraints have their `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property set to `false`, in contrast to views instantiated programmatically. This is because interface builder expects constraints to fully specify the layout of that view.

To modify your frame/bounds/center manually, set this property to `true` in code. This will make the view's layout behave in a way similar to how things worked in the days before AutoLayout, so be aware that any constraints you specify on the view may conflict or behave unexpectedly if you just specify this property when you *actually* want it to be laid out using constraints.

I would suggest that you first consider whether what you actually want to do is specify your label's position through AutoLayout constraints. These days, it is rare that you actually want to specify a position manually, as you have done above.

Comment: This works, although the code I needed was         `titleLabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)`.

Comment: That being said, a little more creativity with AutoLayout allowed me to avoid all this.  Still marking it as correct as it definitely is the answer to my question, even if my question was bad.

Comment: @thumbtackthief Glad you got it sorted. The `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(_:)` method has finally been changed to a property `var translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: Bool` in iOS 9 beta - I believe the documentation always implied it was a property, and it does make more sense! But yes, pre iOS 9 you have to use the method variant, as you have found.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to center the label according the screen size? 
if so, try the below (Note the UIlabel is created programmatically)

```
 var tempLabel:UILabel
 override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

     //gets screen frame size
     var fm: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

     //creates a temp UILabel
     tempLabel = UILabel(frame:  CGRectMake(0, fm.frame.size.height, fm.size.width, fm.size.height))

     //aligns the UIlabel to center
     tempLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

    //adding UIlabel to view
    view.addSubview(tempLabel)
}
```