# UITableView - issue with background image size & position

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, background-image

I want to set a background image in UITableView, when list is empty. I set it by using following code. It is properly visible in iPhone 5. But showing some space in iPhone 6 onward devices.

Please help. I’m novice for iOS development.

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

let bgView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: tableView.frame.size.height))

let ivImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: tableView.frame.size.height))
ivImageView.image = image
ivImageView.tintColor = UIColor.green
ivImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
ivImageView.alpha = 0.05
bgView.addSubview(ivImageView)

tableView.backgroundView = bgView
tableView.backgroundView?.layoutIfNeeded()
tableView.backgroundView?.layoutSubviews()
```

[image: Here is sample snapshot with actual problem]

Comment: Do you want the imageView to be in center or fill the view?

Comment: Check this SO link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31503580/programmatically-set-position-of-swift-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code the absolutely correct.

Problem is that, you may be setting background image during `viewDidLoad().` Instead, try it with `viewWillApper()`. It will set your frame, exact to size of your tableview.

There another options also to do it. Reset image frame after some delay of time using `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`or use `performSelectorWithDelay`.

Let me know if you can't do it.